# Given an array index, how to get the n neighbors before and after index while wrapping?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array and an index, I'd like to return n values surrounding the value at index.

For instance:
Array: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

index: 1

values: 2

Result:
[6,0,1,2,3]

slice comes in handy but I can't get the wrapping requirement working. Is the simplest solution to concat the array and work from that? ([...array, ...array])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the double array and an offset with adjustment for slicing.

```js
const
    getValues = (array, index, values) => {
        let offset = index - values;
        if (offset < 0) offset += array.length;
        return [...array, ...array].slice(offset, offset + 2 * values + 1);
    },
    array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    result = getValues(array, 1, 2);
    
console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this adds much to the answers here already unless it might need to wrap over a size greater than the array length:

```js
const circle_number_for_size = (circle_size) => (number) => {
  const rem = number % circle_size;
  return rem + (rem < 0 ? circle_size : 0);
};

const circle_slice = (array, start, end) => {
  const circle_number = circle_number_for_size(array.length);
  let new_array = [];
  
  for(let i = start; i <= end; i++)
    new_array.push(array[circle_number(i)]);
  
  return new_array;
};

const neighbours = (array, centre_index, offset) =>
  circle_slice(array, centre_index - offset, centre_index + offset);

console.log( ...neighbours([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 1, 2) );
console.log( ...neighbours([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 0, 21) );
```